How to Split a Small Dataset for Survival Analysis: Train/Validation or Include a Test Set?
I am working on survival analysis for pancreatic cancer with a small dataset of 140 samples. The dataset includes WSI and mask data along with survival information.
1. Current Approach
I use 5-fold cross-validation on train/validation splits, resulting in 112 samples for training and 28 for validation in each fold.
2. Suggestion from a Collaborator
Split the dataset into three parts—98 for training, 28 for validation, and 14 for a test set.
Given the small dataset size and the inability to use external datasets (due to the need for masks and survival information), I am unsure if setting aside a test set from the same dataset is reasonable.

Would it be better to rely solely on train/validation results?
Does splitting further into a test set risk underutilizing an already small dataset?

Any insights on best practices for small-sample survival analysis would be greatly appreciated.

This recent question and answer is very similar.
